# dynamic function calls on javascript does not find the target function

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I have a script with a function defined like this:

```
    function getdetails(month, kategorie) {
```

and on a later section I have this:

```
    rdata + `<tr><td onClick="getdetails(${month},${jObj[elem].ID})">${jObj[elem].Kategorie}</td><td align='right';>${jObj[elem].Summe}</td></tr>`;
```

The onClick does respond, but cannot find the function.
Error message is

> (index):1 Uncaught ReferenceError: getdetails is not defined
> at HTMLTableCellElement.onclick ((index):1)

What am I missing out?

Comment: _"What am I missing out?"_ - A [mcve] -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: it looks like a scope issue. So I inserted the function creation into the same block inside of the function, where the data is written into the table. But I had no success.